# AngularJS - 404 error on page reload after Hashbang removal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hashbang

After removing the hashbang from my routes using

```js
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Now when visiting a page, for example "domain.com/download", it will work. But if I reloaded this exact page, it would give me an 404 Error. Links like "domain.com/download" can only be opened by typing "domain.com/#!/download". Once it loads it would redirect me to the normal "domain.com/download" page again.

Im using v1.3.2 for routing and v1.6.3 for the rest (dont ask me why I didnt make this site lol).

Comment: you need to configure your routing (in `.htaccess`)

Comment: Is that usual? Because I didn't have to do this to make the hashbangs themselves working.

Comment: Yes, it is usual, because you need to do this to make URLs *without* a hashbang work.  (Your angular app is actually at the path "/"; the hash part of the URL is ignored when determining he path, so "/#!/whatever" still points to "/".   "/download" points to a different path, by default, which is not your app; so you need to reconfigure your webserver to point all urls at the same path, where Angular can figure out what to do with it from there.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the [AngularJS Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) says:

> Using this mode requires URL rewriting on server side, basically you
>   have to rewrite all your links to entry point of your application
>   (e.g. index.html). Requiring a  tag is also important for this
>   case, as it allows AngularJS to differentiate between the part of the
>   url that is the application base and the path that should be handled
>   by the application.

You'll have to change your `.htaccess` to something like:

```
RewriteEngine On 
Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /#/$1 [L]
```

Comment: (This answer assumes they're using apache as the webserver; other webservers will need different configuration.  note also minor typo on `.htaccess`)

Comment: Fixed the typo.  Yup this assumes apache though you can lookup what you'd need for other configurations pretty easily.

Comment: This worked, thanks.